# Makefile target multiple sources but only one target

Tags: makefile

while working on my makefile i need to write rule that executes:

```
$(GRIT) $(GRITFLAGS) INPUTFILE -ff $(addsuffix .grit,$(basename INPUTFILE)) -o grit.c
```

Whereas INPUTFILE is a list of xxx.png files. In the same directory there is always a xxx.grit file which needs to be passed via the -ff option. However all pairs of .png and .grit files provide THE SAME output file, grit.c (grit uses file appending).
I tried to use the rules for patterns but when i wanted to do a rule like grit.c: %.png %.grit, however it seems not be allowed to use patterns for a target that does not contain anything like the pattern.

Any idea how to solve my problem?

Edit:
The major problem is, that i can not pass lits of input files (as done in the example above) towards GRIT. This is only to show my problem. I need to call GRIT for every single .png/.grit-File combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grit.c: $(images)
    for png in $?; do \
      $(GRIT) $(GRITFLAGS) $$png -ff $${png%.png}.grit -o $@; \
    done
```

Comment: Wouldnt this simply pass lists of .png and .grit files towards GRIT? The problem is, GRIT can only take one input & grit file to match them together.

Comment: @WodkaRHR It would be helpful if you mentioned that in your question, you said `INPUTFILE` was a list of images.

Comment: Sorry, i edited the question according to this unspecified information.

Comment: unexpected end of file error occurs

these are my rules:
GFXSRC= $(shell find asset/gfx -type f -iname '*.png')
GFXC= $(BLDPATH)/asset/gfx/gfx.c

$(GFXC): $(GFXSRC)
 $(shell mkdir -p $(dir $(GFXC)))
 for png in $?; do
     echo png
     $(GRIT) $(GRITFLAGS) $$png -ff $${png%.png}.grit -o $@
 done